# Unable to see keras model graph in Tensorboard when using TensorFlow 2.0 Alpha

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0

I am trying custom training on TensorFlow 2.0 alpha and at the same time I am trying to add some metrics and my training graph to TensorBoard. Consider the following contrived example

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


def create_model():
    inp = Input((32, ))
    net = Dense(16, activation="relu")(inp)
    net = Dense(8, activation="relu")(net)
    net = Dense(2, activation=None)(net)
    return Model(inp, net)


@tf.function
def grad(model, loss, x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_ = model(x)
        loss_value = loss(y_true=y, y_pred=y_)
    return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)


@tf.function
def train_step(model, loss, optimizer, features, labels):
    loss_value, grads = grad(model, loss, features, labels)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
    return loss_value


def train():
    tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True, profiler=True)

    with tf.summary.create_file_writer("model").as_default():
        model = create_model()

        loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)

        for i in range(10):
            tf.summary.experimental.set_step(i)

            features = tf.random.normal((16, 32))
            labels = tf.random.normal((16, 2))
            loss_value = train_step(model, loss, optimizer, features, labels)
            print(loss_value)

        tf.summary.trace_export("model", profiler_outdir="model")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    train()
```

This, does not show the model graph properly, on doing

```
tensorboard --logdir model
```

In the graphs tab I am seeing [image: tensorboard]

I am getting the graph when I am training through model.fit or estimator. For example, here is the graphs section when I use `model_to_estimator` to convert a model

[image: model_to_estiamtor]

[The guide article](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough) does not track metrics through tensorboard, and I did not find any sections on the new workflow for custom adding and tracking of metrics in TensorBoard on alpha (https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha). My contrived implementation is based on the API documentation of tf.summary (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/summary)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True,show_dtype=True,rankdir="LR")` to plot a keras model graph .